# Окно "Источники данных"

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2012

Как открыть окно "Источники данных" в visual studio 2012? Здесь http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/yft2c9ad.aspx написано

> > Открытие окна "Источники данных"
>
> В меню Данные выберите пункт Показать
> источники данных.

но у меня нет меню "Данные".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Пункт меню Вид => Другие окна => Источники данных (Visual Studio Ultimate  2012 Update 1). Либо сочетание клавиш Shift+Alt+D. В зависимости от типа проекта данный пункт меню может не отображаться.